# "update query" on slim framework returns error

Tags: php, slim

im using Slim Framework for routing and Postman to update the data but it returns "Slim Application Error..".. where did i go wrong? on my insert it works just fine

this is my update route

```
    //Update
    $app->put('/citizens/update/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $fName = $request->getParam('f_name');
    $mName = $request->getParam('m_name');
    $lName = $request->getParam('l_name');
    $updateData = Test::update($fName, $mName, $lName, $id);
});
```

this is my Test class for update

```
public static function update($fName, $mName, $lName, $id)
    {
        $db = new DatabaseHandler;
        $updateData = $db->update(TABLE, [
            'f_name' => $fName,
            'm_name' => $mName,
            'l_name' => $lName,
            ])->where(['id' => $id])->save();
        return $updateData;
    }
```

This is my handler for update query

```
public function update($table, $conditions)
    {
        $this->query = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ";
        foreach ($conditons as $column => $val)
        {
            $this->bind[] = $val;
            $this->query = $this->query.$column.'=?';
            if($counter+1 < count($conditions))
            {
                $this->query = $this->query.", ";
            }
            $counter++;
        }
        return $this;
    }
public function where($conditions)
    {
        $this->query = $this->query." WHERE ";
        foreach($conditions as $condition => $val)
        {
            $this->query = $this->query.$condition.'='.$val;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question so we can understand the problem better. I can see in line 4 of the `update` function you're using `TABLE`. What is that?

Comment: im just new to slim ddnt know how to post the error but after reading the docs, this is the error i encountered "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=4' at line 1"
btw on TABLE i used define.